# Not disposing Entity Framework DataContext causes SQL Server memory issues?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, sql-server-2008, datacontext

I have an ASP.NET MVC app that I am developing, very few users but SQL Server is hogging memory like crazy.

I am wondering if it could be due to the Entity Framework. I have been following tutorials and books like ASP MVC Pro 2 for guidance but none of them show to explicitly dispose of the data context.

If you don't dispose of it, does SQL Server continue to hold memory for the request?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should of course dispose `ObjectContext` / `DbContext`. That is why it implements `IDisposable`. But your problem is not related to not disposing `ObjectContext` because SQL server hanldes its memory without any relation to client. You should check how many data are processed in your queries.

Comment: the problem is that there are no queries running but yet the server is using over 3GB of memory